# Getting information from dataframe after a groupby function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the maximum value in a particular column. After that I was the corresponding row value with all the attributes. How can I do this?

```
SYM NUM DATE
A    3   23
A    4   5
B    6   14
B    7   13
```

After applying group by I get maximum value in NUM row as

```
SYM NUM
A    4
B    7
```

I want the corresponding DATE value

```
SYM NUM DATE
A    4   5
B    7   13
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: What would you like it to look like if there is more than one instance of the max value per value in the category column?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `idxmax`

```
In [134]: df.loc[df.groupby('SYM')['NUM'].idxmax()]
Out[134]:
  SYM  NUM  DATE
1   A    4     5
3   B    7    13
```